# Use multiple search criteria in CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am wondering if it is possible to search multiple values with the `CHARINDEX` function? For example, in addition to searching for the `','` (comma) I would also like to search for a single character, 'K'. If either the `','` or the  `'K'` is found then it will output the string 'Native SQL'.

```
DECLARE @OPRID CHAR(30)
SET @OPRID = NULL

SELECT @OPRID = case (charindex(',',
cast(context_info as char(128)))) 
when 0 then 'Native SQL'
else 
substring(cast(context_info as
CHAR(128)),1,(charindex(',',cast(context_info as char(128)))-1))
end
FROM sys.sysprocesses
```

Comment: `PATINDEX('%[K,]%', ...)`. This is still limited in that it only happens to work for searching single characters; for more complex patterns T-SQL falls short.

Comment: I used that, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work as there is some conversion from character to hexidecimal.

Comment: You would still need to cast `context_info` regardless, since it's a `binary(128)`. None of the T-SQL string functions operate on binary types (or, at least, they don't typically do so *correctly*, injecting implicit conversions into the mix). This is true for `CHARINDEX` as well as `PATINDEX`. If your value contains binary wotsits, consider going through a hexstring conversion (`CONVERT(VARCHAR(256), context_info, 2)`); searching that may be more convenient.

Comment: I tried using the following, but think I have a Syntax issue: `SELECT @OPRID = case ((CONVERT(VARCHAR(256), context_info, 2)))patindex('%[K,]%',
cast(context_info as char(128)))) 
when 0 then 'Native SQL'`

Comment: Try `SELECT @OPRID = CASE WHEN context_info NOT LIKE '%[K,]%' THEN 'Native SQL' ELSE STUFF(context_info, PATINDEX('%[K,]%', CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), context_info)), 128, '') END`. `LIKE` will do implicit conversions (why? because it just does), so we don't need an extra conversion there. And `STUFF` is just good whenever it's usable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,  I'm not seeing why something like `IF (CONVERT(VARCHAR(256),@OPRID)) <> 'K' BEGIN` would not work? It does not work, but seems like it should? I'll admit I am not very familiar with hexadecimal/binary data types.

Comment: That will work if you're looking for the value `0x4B000000...` (with `...` any amount of `00` you like. Converting the binary simply reinterprets it as a string in the database default collation (the vast majority of which have ASCII as a subset, and will thus have `K` at code point 113, 0x4b), where NUL (0x00) is ignored if it occurs at the end (it also results in output being cut off, even if more bytes follow). If that's what you meant by "the single character `K`", I misinterpreted the question. Ultimately SQL Server is quite ignorant about binary values.

Comment: I guess this is going to be difficult to ascertain. Whats happening is this code is running inside a SQL trigger, and inserting a row in an audit table with the OPRID appears as one letter 'K', but it is actually including 2 zeros between each character converted to hexadecimal. So OPRID value 'KTESTER' is being inserted as 'K' (in the trigger) but has an actual character length of 14 (double the length of 'KTESTER'). Once the row is inserted, what is the best way to query it? Doing a `SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(256),AUDIT_OPRID)) = 'K'` does not appear to work.

Comment: Those "two zeroes" are the telltale sign of a Unicode string. See what `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(64), AUDIT_OPRID)` gives you.

Comment: This ended up working, `substring(replace(context_info, 0x00,0x),1,(charindex(',',replace(context_info, 0x00,0x))-1))` It does a hexadecimal replacement of the additional 00s added between each character. 00 is also the end of a string, which is why I was only seeing the first character. Replace function is doing an implicit cast to character.